# Ubuntu 10.04.4 LTS - cURL SSL certificate permission denied

Tags: ubuntu, openssl, curl

After extensive searching I haven't found documentation of this problem yet.
Suddenly, possibly following a software update(?), cURL fails to establish SSL connections with this error:

```
curl: (35) error:0200100D:system library:fopen:Permission denied
```

With strace, I found out that it's trying to open an SSL certificate which is denied:

open("/etc/ssl/certs/3c58f906.0", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = -1 EACCES (Permission denied)

This certificate is a symlink which points to AddTrust_External_Root.pem which in turn is a symlink to /usr/share/ca-certificates/mozilla/AddTrust_External_Root.crt. The permissions are such that indeed my user isn't allowed to access it:

```
ls -l /usr/share/ca-certificates/mozilla/AddTrust_External_Root.crt 
-rw-r----- 1 root ssl-cert 1521 2011-09-01 18:48 /usr/share/ca-certificates/mozilla/AddTrust_External_Root.crt
```

There's probably a reason why this file isn't world-readable, but it's stopping cURL from functioning. Does anybody know the reason, and, more importantly, a safe and secure solution?

Comment: Thanks you for aving me hours of debugging. strace -fp <pid> (of the server's master process)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no reason for this file not to be world readable. It's not anything unique to your system and is included in the default install: http://packages.ubuntu.com/lucid/all/ca-certificates/filelist

Generally I think anything under /usr/share/ may be world readable (since its under "share").

Now why this file is not world readable on your system is the real question. A bug probably.

Comment: Thank you Edmunds and @cjc. I'll just chmod a+r the certificate file then.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm.  It's world readable on my Lucid installation:

```
$ ls -l /usr/share/ca-certificates/mozilla/AddTrust_External_Root.crt
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1521 2011-09-01 16:48 /usr/share/ca-certificates/mozilla/AddTrust_External_Root.crt
```

There appears to be something wrong with your installation, or a previous administrator changed the ownership/permissions for obscure reasons.